# Getting access to UI thread using robolectric

Tags: android, multithreading, runnable, robolectric

I'm having trouble getting the main UI thread inside a robolectric(version 1.1) testcase. The application method I'm testing has the following check in it:

```
if (Thread.currentThread() != Looper.getMainLooper().getThread()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "This method should be called from the Main UI Thread");
        }
    }
```

This check fails when invoked in the following way:

```
    @Test
public void maTest() {

    Runnable task = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            adapter.testThreadPrecondition();

        }
    };

    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(task);
}
```

Also tried "runOnUiThread", and got same check to fail. What is going on? different main loopers?

Comment: Also tried with an AsyncTask, but nothing inside "onPostExecute" seems to get called (or gets called but fails silently)                                     



        task.execute();
        Robolectric.getBackgroundScheduler().runOneTask();
        Robolectric.getUiThreadScheduler().runOneTask();

Comment: ever found a solution to this?

Comment: sadly no, I removed the tests instead.

Answer (score 0):

Put the code that checks whether the looper thread is the current thread into a method, say `ValidateRunningOnLooperThread()`.

Then, in the unit test use a mocking framework, such as [Mockito](http://mockito.org/) to [mock that method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14970516/use-mockito-to-mock-some-methods-but-not-others) to just return successfully.