# JUnit Test : Forcing exception from internal method call

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, spring-test

I am trying to write a test case which covers a piece of code written inside a `catch` block. This is how it goes:

I have two methods in class `A`.

```
class A{

     public SomeReturnType m1()
     {
       try{
            m2();
         }catch(SomeException ex)
         {
          //handler code for SomeException (This is what I want to test). 
         }
     }

     public SomeReturnType m2() throws SomeException
     {
            //Some logic
     }
}
```

I am wondering How can a force this exception when `m2()` is called from the unit test case of method `m1()`? Any solutions using Mockito or any other testing lib?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you suggested, Mockito would be a classic tool for such a usecase:

```
// Initialization - should probably be in the @Before method:
A a = Mockito.spy(new A());
Mockito.doThrow(new SomeException("yay!")).when(a).m2();

// Actual test:
SomeResult actualResult = a.m1();
assertEquals(someExpectedResult, actualResult); // or some other assertion
```

The above snippet creates a `spy`ied object (think of it as an anonymous class that extends `A`) with the defined behavior that when `m2()` is called, a `SomeException` will be thrown. 
Then the code goes on to call the real `m1()` method, which itself calls `m2()`, and has to handle the exception.

Comment: I guess here I am not calling m1() method,so how would code in the catch block will come into picture....Can you elaborate more?

Comment: @DanglingPiyush I added some detail to the answer - let me know if that wasn't what you were looking for.

Comment: m1 is calling m2 not vice versa?

Comment: @DanglingPiyush yes, indeed, I switched `m1` and `m2`. Mea culpa.

Answer (score 1):

Of couse partial mock can solve your problem but there is some flaw in the design itself. Your API provides two methods with same signature one with richer exception management functionality. Pattern decorator seem to be more elegant here and no partial mock required to properly test it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not interested in restructuring this class, the best way would be to use a partial mock. Stub out m2() to throw an exception when called, and then call m1().

[Use Mockito to mock some methods but not others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14970516/use-mockito-to-mock-some-methods-but-not-others)