# Mockito Spy - partial mocking not working?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

My scenario is pretty simple. Trying to use partial mocks, according to last answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14970516/use-mockito-to-mock-some-methods-but-not-others) and [the documentation of Mockito](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#13) itself. My test is:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    ClassUnderTest realObject = new ClassUnderTest();
    ClassUnderTest spy = spy(realObject);
    when(spy.methodB()).thenThrow(new Exception("Testing"));

    spy.methodA();
}
```

and the class under test is:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.NotImplementedException;

public class ClassUnderTest {

    int methodB(){
        throw new NotImplementedException("Not implemented");
    }

    public int methodA(){
        methodB();
        return 0;
    }

}
```

I would expect that my spying object would call the method B raising the "Testing" exception while actually the real method is called throwing the "Not implemented" exception. It behaves like I don't have a partial mock behavior in place

Why is that? What am I missing?

EDIT: As RPresle suggested, I tried using the syntax

```
doThrow(new Exception("Testing")).when(spy.methodB());
```

However, I get an UnfinishedStubbingException:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException: 
Unfinished stubbing detected here:
 -> at SimpleTest.test(SimpleTest.java:15)

E.g. thenReturn() may be missing.
Examples of correct stubbing:
when(mock.isOk()).thenReturn(true);
when(mock.isOk()).thenThrow(exception);
doThrow(exception).when(mock).someVoidMethod();
Hints:
 1. missing thenReturn()
 2. you are trying to stub a final method, you naughty developer!
 3: you are stubbing the behaviour of another mock inside before 'thenReturn' instruction if completed

at SimpleTest.test(SimpleTest.java:15)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Could anyone provide more guidance?

Comment: You did `.when(spy.methodB());` whereas RPresle wrote `.when(spy).methodB();`

Comment: You are right. Thank you very much. Do you think I should remove my edit, or could my "typo" be useful for future readers?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Refering to [this tutorial](http://blog.javabien.net/2009/06/21/mockitos-partial-mocks-testing-real-objects-just-got-easier/) on Mockito, you can see that Mockito do call the original method.

> There is only one caveat to this syntax. The real rule.createFileTemplate() method will be called once. This can have a lot of side effects and might even fail throwing an exception (very often a NPE). To solve this, you can (should?) use this alternative Mockito syntax:
>
> ```
> doReturn(mockFileTemplate).when(rule).createFileTemplate();
> ```

In order to avoid this you should use the other syntax of Mockito `doReturn().when()`

```
doThrow(new Exception("Testing")).when(spy).methodB();
```

Hope this help.

EDIT :

Please notice that the structure is a little bit different than the `when().thenReturn()`.

```
doThrow(new Exception("Testing"))
    .when(spy)
    .methodB();
```