# jUnit skip Method-Call in injectmock-method in a test

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito, junit4

I've got a `@InjectMocks cut` which is the Class i want to test. There is a `deleteX()` and a `init()` Method in it.
`deleteX()` is calling `init()` before finishing - how can i skip this call in my test, because every time i just get a `NullPointer Exception`.

```
public void deleteX() {
    // some things
    init();
}
```

I just want to skip it, because I've got test methods for both of them and don't want big and double code.
I can't do `Mockito.doNothing().when(cut).deleteX();` because `@InjectMocks` is not a `Mockobject`.

Comment: whatever is calling deleteX in your application code can call init() directly afterward and then you can remove the init() call from delete()

Comment: @PeterGelderbloem It´s called by an JSF Page in a `p:commandbutton` and action can´t call 2 methods and i´m afraid, because `deleteX()` need  to be called first.

Comment: You need to provide mocks for whatever is currently null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way to achieve what you want - it is called "partial mocking". See this question for more details - [Use Mockito to mock some methods but not others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14970516/use-mockito-to-mock-some-methods-but-not-others).

Given a `ClassUnderTest` as follows:

```
class ClassUnderTest {

    public void init() {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }

    public void deleteX() {
        // some things
        init();
    }
}
```

This test will pass:

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.doNothing;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Spy;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ClassUnderTestTest {

    @Spy
    private ClassUnderTest classUnderTest;

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        // given
        doNothing().when(classUnderTest).init();
        // when
        classUnderTest.deleteX();
        // then
        verify(classUnderTest).init();
    }
}
```

All method invocations on object annotated with `@Spy` will be real, except for mocked ones. In this case `init()` invocation is mocked to do nothing, instead of throwing an exception.

If you need dependencies injected into class under test, that needs to be done in `@Before` method, e.g.:

```
private ClassUnderTest classUnderTest;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    ClassUnderTest cut = new ClassUnderTest();
    // inject dependencies into `cut`
    classUnderTest = Mockito.spy(cut);
}
```