# Test method of Singleton object using Powermock

Tags: singleton, powermockito

I would like to test a public method1 as well as mock the private method createJSON of Singleton class.

```
public class SingletonClass {
    private static SingletonClass singletonInstance = new SingletonClass();
    private SingletonClass() {
    }

    public static SingletonClass getInstance() {
        return singletonInstance;
    }

    public JSONObject method1(int id, String str)
        throws JSONException {
        JSONObject loginJSON = createJSON(id, str);
        return loginJSON;
    }

    private JSONObject createJSON(int id, String str){
        return new JSONObject().put("id", id).put("str", str);
    }
```

}

Could anyone help on this?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need a *partial mock*. A partial mock will allow you to mock a subset of the methods of the class you are working with, but not others.

[This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14970516/use-mockito-to-mock-some-methods-but-not-others) explains how to use partial mocks.

Comment: but in my case I have a singleton class and need to mock public method which internally calls private method. So I need to mock public as well as private methods of Singleton class.