# Mock a method inside a constructor of a class

Tags: java, junit, constructor, mockito

I am new to mockito. Lets say I have a class like this

```
public class MyClass {
    int a;
    String b;
    public MyClass(int a) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = draw();
        System.out.println("class is created");
    }

    public String draw() {
        System.out.println("my");
        return "b";
    }

    public void apple() {
        System.out.println("apple");
    }
}
```

I am writing a JUnit test using Mockito where I am creating a object of the class by using the constructor. Is it possible to mock the draw() method when I am instating the class?

Comment: Can you share your test's code, or at least the relevant parts of it?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Your class under test doesn't have any dependency on another object. So there is nothing to mock.

Comment: you don't always have to use mockito. For your case why you need to mock anything. use simple junit test.

Comment: Since you are writing tests, you probably aim for writing testable code. If so, you should avoid constructors doing more then merely assigning parameters to fields. See [here](http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/flaw-constructor-does-real-work/) for an excellent argumentation on this topic.

Answer (score 6):

Not clear why you need the `Mockito` here. This is a solution without `Mockito`.

In your test create an instance of `MyClass` with overridden `draw()` method:

```
final MyClass myClass = new MyClass() {
    @Override
    public String draw() {
        return "mock data";
    }
}

// Now test your class as you want
```

Answer (score 1):

You could turn to do *partial mocking* using spies (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14970516/use-mockito-to-mock-some-methods-but-not-others) for how to do that).

But as usual: when people start thinking about complex ways to use mocking framework, the **real** answer is: step back and improve your production code. Your constructor should do *only* simple initialisation things.

In your case, one reasonable approach would be: don't call an internal method to compute the value of that field - but **pass** that value to the constructor (in other words - use dependency injection).

And you could still do something like:

```
public MyClass(int a) {
  this(a, draw());
}

MyClass(int a, String b) { 
  this.a = a; ...
```

Now your unit tests can happily use that ctor that takes *two* arguments - and your need to **mock** anything vanishes completely.

Answer (score 0):

One way to test your class with **Mockito** will be,

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

public class TestMyClass {

    @Mock
    private MyClass clazz;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testDraw() {
        when(clazz.draw()).thenReturn("My mock hello");
        assertEquals("My mock hello", clazz.draw());
    }
}
```

Comment: Then again you are mocking the ClassUnderTest

Answer (score 0):

Complementing the solutions given, the constructor can also receive the method to mock as a function.

```
import java.util.function.Supplier;
    
public class MyClass {
    int a;
    String b;

    public MyClass(int a, Supplier<String> draw) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = draw==null? draw() : draw.get();
        System.out.println("class is created");
     }
        
    public String draw() {
        System.out.println("my");
        return "b";
    }
        
    public void apple() {
         System.out.println("apple");
     }
}
```