# JAX-WS, simulate timeout from service implementation

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jax-ws

I have Service Endpoint Implementation, and I want to simulate timeout scenarios for testing purposes. The implementation method handles the request. How do I "ignore" the request from within the method, showing up as a timeout for the calling service?

Comment: mock the method with timeout?

Comment: Are your familiar with Junit? Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14970516/use-mockito-to-mock-some-methods-but-not-others

Comment: You get the question wrong. I'm doing end-to-end testing where the system components are actually called, and have to simulate the network failure from one system component. Basically, when the service receives a request, it should check if the failure simulation is on and silently ignore the request, resulting in a timeout on the callers end.