# Verifying argument sent to method not invoked directly in mocked class using Mockito

Tags: java, mockito

I have a class where I want a method stubbed out, but I want to see what argument was passed to that stubbed method. However, I won't be invoking the method directly in the test, but instead invoking something that will eventually call it. So far, examples I've found for verifying arguments is only for methods that are directly invoked.

Here's an example that illustrates the problem:

```
public class FooTest
{
    @Test
    public void testFoo()
    {
        Foo foo = mock(Foo.class);
        when(foo.mockableMethod(anyString())).thenReturn("dummy");

        foo.parentMethod(true);

        ArgumentCaptor<String> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);
        verify(foo).mockableMethod(captor.capture());
        assertEquals("foo", captor.getValue());
    }

    class Foo
    {
        public void parentMethod(boolean isFoo)
        {
            mockableMethod(isFoo ? "foo" : "bar");
        }

        protected String mockableMethod(String passedArgument)
        {
            // Only returning for brevity; assume it does a lot more.
            return passedArgument;
        }
    }
}
```

This yields the following error:

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError:
Wanted but not invoked:
foo.mockableMethod(<Capturing argument>);
-> at FooTest.testFoo(FooTest.java:32)

However, there were other interactions with this mock:
foo.parentMethod("foo");
-> at FooTest.testFoo(FooTest.java:29)
```

Is this even possible? This setup works just fine if I verify `parentMethod` instead of `mockableMethod`, but that's not very useful for me. In this example, I specifically want to make sure that the stubbed method `mockableMethod` is called with "foo" if `parentMethod` is called with `true`.

The only alternative I can think of is doing something like this within `testFoo`:

```
when(foo.mockableMethod("foo")).thenReturn("dummy");
```

... but I'm not sure how to catch the case where an argument other than "foo" is sent to it. `thenThrow` and fail on that? Suggestions welcome!

Comment: don't you need Partial Mocks? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14970516/use-mockito-to-mock-some-methods-but-not-others

Comment: What you want is a spy, not a mock.

Comment: For some reason, I thought `spy` didn't let you stub methods. I was wrong. Just changing from `mock` to `spy` absolutely fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

`spy` can stub methods just like `mock` can, and switching to `spy` fixes the issue:

```
Foo foo = spy(new Foo());
```

The rest of the code stays the same. However, in my *actual* code, I need to use `doReturn` before `when` because I didn't want it invoked:

```
doReturn("dummy").when(foo).mockableMethod(anyString());
```

(courtesy of comments on the original question)