# How do I force Mockito to call underlaying functions with arguments?

Tags: java, mocking, mockito

I have this:

```
class MyClass {
    private String foo;
    public getFoo() { return foo; }
    public setFoo(String foo) { this.foo = foo; }
}
```

Now, I want to mock it.

```
MyClass m = Mockito.mock(MyClass.class);
when(m.getFoo()).thenCallRealMethod();
when(m.setFoo(Mockito.anyString())).thenCallRealMethod();
```

But this gives me this compile error:

```
'void' type not allowed here
```

Using `thenCallRealMethod()` seems to work for methods with no arguments, but I cannot get it to work with arguments. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Since void methods cannot return anything, including a mockito matcher, you need to use a different syntax for those:

```
doCallRealMethod().when(m).setFoo(Mockito.anyString())
```

Comment: I was just about to write that myself, but you were faster :)

Answer (score 1):

You could also spy on the object, this will only mock the defined methods

For further information [Use Mockito to mock some methods but not others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14970516/use-mockito-to-mock-some-methods-but-not-others)

Comment: Ehm? I want to call the underlaying method. Not do nothing.

Comment: Sorry I miss understood the question ;)

Comment: Yes. That's why I used `thenCallRealMethod`

Comment: I corrected the answer now.