# how to mock a method call inside another method in same class

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, junit, mockito

I am trying to test a method `methodB` (as shown in the code below). I want to return directly from `methodA` without going into the actual code of `methodA`.
I have used `when/thenReturn` and `doReturn/when` but didn't get any success. The test case goes into the real code of `methodA`. Also tried using `spy` with Class `A` instance but didn't get any success.

Actual Class

```
class A{
  
  fun methodA(String a): String{

    // do something
    throw new Exception("An error occured");
  }

  fun methodB(String b): String{

    try{
      methodA("test")
    } catch (e: Exception){
      println(e.message());
    }
  }

}
```

Test Class

```
class ATest{

    private lateinit var a: A

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        a= A() // I am initializing services in real scenario
    }

    @Test
    fun `when methodB is not valid then throw Exception`(){

        val aMock = mock(A)
        Mockito.when(aMock.methodA("test") )
            .thenThrow(UserException.INVALID_REQUEST())


        // When
        val exception: Exception = Assert.assertThrows(
            UserException::class.java
        ) {
            a.methodB("test b")
        }

        val expectedMessage = "INVALID"
        val actualMessage = exception.message

        // Then
        Assert.assertTrue(actualMessage!!.contains(expectedMessage))
    }

   
}
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: `a` needs to be an actual mock. You are creating the object yourself in your code.

Comment: Same behavior with mock, question updated.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand your question. I think this https://stackoverflow.com/q/14970516/2587435 might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
val a = A()
val aSpy = Mockito.spy(a)
Mockito.when(aSpy.methodA(ArgumentMatchers.any())).thenThrow(UserException.INVALID_REQUEST())
```

you need to get a real instance of class A and then wrap it inside a programmable wrapper which is a spy.
The param matcher of the `when` statement is the 2nd point of failure since "Test" is not the same instance then the "test b" string. So you dont need to verify some parameter so skip it.

If you want to verify the used parameter you can use a captor instead of ANY().