# Mock a method from a class that is under testing

Tags: java, mockito

I want to use Mockito to mock a method from a class which is under testing. This method is called in the method which I want to test. How can I do that?

```
public class MyClass {
    public String dependencyMethod() {
        // Some implementation
        return "actual_result";
    }

    public String methodToTest() {
        String result = dependencyMethod();
        // Some other implementation using result
        return result;
    }
}
```

```
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

public class TestMyClass {

    @Test
    public void testMethodToTest() {
       // TODO: Write implementation here
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14970516/use-mockito-to-mock-some-methods-but-not-others).

Comment: I'd suggest using a mockito spy instead of a mock. The link Andrew S posted has some examples.

Comment: I would try very hard to not do that. You should mock the dependencies, but never the code under test. It's too easy, by accident, to mock something instead of actually testing it. Use of mocking frameworks is IMHO also a code smell. Clearly the code was not written test-first or at least with testing in mind, and now you're in a poorly designed code base where testing is hard. I'd try to refactor, which of course is also hard cause you don't have tests to tell you if you break something. Be careful and good luck. :-)